# Repeat sound every time a button is pushed

Tags: android, audio, repeat

I'm testing Android sound implementation. I have an "*imagenButton*" and when I push it, a method "`musica()`" is called. Is really simple:

```
public void musica(View v) {
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Migrunido);
    if(m.isPlaying()) {
        m.stop();
        } 
    else {
        m.start();
        }
    }
```

It works, but want when I press the button, the sound repeats. I was reading a lot about threads and I have to prepare it before "`stop()`" but can't fix it.

I have to prepare my method? Or what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void playAudio(int id) {

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,id);
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }else{
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

if this doesn't work try `mediaPlayer.prepare();` before you start.

Comment: " release() " close app :/

Dont know why